# A better way to catalogue duplicate questions?

Tags: feature-request, bug

Right now, when a question B (posted at time t+ t1) is marked as a duplicate of question A (posted at time t), and I attempt to access it (question B), I am taken to Question A. Now this often results in loss of information in the form of answers, comments and the details of the question itself (of question B) being unavailable to the user. Marking Q's as duplicates is fine, but we need the feature where the duplicate question is still available to view. There may be differences in semantics between the questions which need to be available and can lead to better answers to the original Q.

Follow-on Q: Is there a way to merge questions. Some of the details requested and sub-Q's in the duplicates may be different and may enhance the original Q as well.

Duplicates must be a [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) set

Comment: If you're logged in, then when you click on question B you should be able to see question B.  It's only when you're not logged in that when you click on question B you'll be redirected to question A.  The idea is that some random person who finds the site by Googling may be unfamiliar with the Stackexchange system, so it's better to direct them to the question that actually has answers rather than the question that doesn't.

Comment: This was not the case. Hence my Q on meta. Bug perhaps? I will check again anyway.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Yeah, it's possible it's a bug.  What's the question you're trying to access?

Comment: It may be the case of merging. You can add `?noredirect=1` to the url (of question you want to visit) to stop automatic redirection.

Comment: Yes, there is a way for moderators to merge questions.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Does it happen ?