# Very much delay by Meta Bot in posting questions in the room

Tags: bug

As we know, the primary room of the site is [Hinduism](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) room. There are two [feeds](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/15189/hinduism?tab=feeds) in the room which posts questions from the main site and meta.

Generally these feeds update every 5 minutes. But it is not happening these days with meta Bot. Since many days, the Bot Meta Bot is not updating these days, Meta Bot is posting the question in the main room with nearly 30 minutes delay.

If we observe recent questions on Meta,

[The Hinduism Stack Exchange Bhashya](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/887/the-hinduism-stack-exchange-bhashya) was asked June 21 4:50 whereas it is posted in the room at 5:30 with a **delay of forty minutes**.

[A better way to catalogue duplicate questions?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-better-way-to-catalogue-duplicate-questions) was asked Jun 17 at 2:08 whereas it was posted at 3:38 with a **delay of more than hour**.

[How does this SE handle questions that obviously have ulterior motives?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/how-does-this-se-handle-questions-that-obviously-have-ulterior-motives) was asked Jun 12 at 2:45 and was posted in the room at 3:10 AM with a **delay of 25 minutes**.

[How does this site deal with aliases?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/how-does-this-site-deal-with-aliases) was asked Jun 9 at 5:56 and was posted in the chat room at 07:20 with a **delay of more than an hour**.

Other questions were also posted after an hour. This delay is becoming a reason to miss the questions posted on meta. So, changes should be made to the feed and it should be updated.

But this question is posted after 7 minutes. It's weird.

Comment: I don't think  this would be specific to Hinduism.SE.

Comment: This is specific to metabot only. Other bots and other sites are working pretty well.